# Customize the form used by Staff user to change password

Tags: django

In my project I need to set some certain fields to `ltr` direction because the whole project is in `rtl` direction so this is what I do:

**admin.py**

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})


class CustomAdminPasswordChangeForm(AdminPasswordChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})


class CustomPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['old_password'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
        self.fields['new_password1'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
        self.fields['new_password2'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
```

And then:

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    change_password_form = CustomAdminPasswordChangeForm
```

The above 3 forms work as expected, however the `CustomAdminPasswordChangeForm` is for when the `Superuser` is changing the password. This form does not ask for Old Password.

But when a `Staff` logs into Admin site, another form is used to change the password which asks for Old Password too.

I have customized that form too (`CustomPasswordChangeForm` above) but I can't find how to set it in my `UserAdmin` class?

Answer (score 0):

The `password_change` URL used by the authenticated user is a separate URL and not part of the `UserAdmin`. In order to modify that, you will have to create a new `CustomPasswordChangeView` that overrides the existing password change view. Here is how the view should look:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView


class MyPasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):

    form_class = MyCustomPasswordChangeForm
```

And in your `urls.py`, you have to add this view in place of the password_change route and ensure that it is called before the admin URLs are called:

```
path(
        "password_change/", views.MyPasswordChangeView.as_view(), name="password_change"
    ),
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for late reply. I'm confused now because I don't understand where to create that view? and my custom form?

Answer (score -1):

This field does not exist in the *UserAdmin* class ([**admin.py**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L44)).

If you look at the source code of the URLs you see that the `PasswordChangeView` ([**urls.py**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/urls.py)) is registered at the *password_change* endpoint:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path(
        "password_change/", views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name="password_change"
    ),
    ...
]
```

The `PasswordChangeView` holds the `PasswordChangeForm` ([**views.py**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L348)) which you may override with your `CustomPasswordChangeForm`.

This means, you can't change this in the **UserAdmin** class. You have to write a new `CustomPasswordChangeView` inheriting from `PasswordChangeView` and replace the form with your `CustomPasswordChangeForm`.

Finally you have to override the admin URLs and reroute to this new `CustomPasswordChangeView`:

```py
def _get_urls() -> list:
    original_urls = admin.site.urls
    ...
    # Search & override the "password_change/" URL
    # path('password_change/', views.CustomPasswordChangeView.as_view(), name="password_change"),


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', _get_urls()),
    ...
]
```

At this point, you may decide this is not worth it and you may just write your own login/registration views.

**Always remember:** The admin page is not actually intended to be used by your regular user. It's..., well..., an administration tool, that in best case is never used. But when it is used, it's used by Programmers who exactly know the project and have no problems with certain limitations, in your case LTR & RTL.

Comment: Staff users are allowed, and supposed, to log into Admin site.

Comment: And it is somehow funny that you believe  in a news publishing site, the staff who is supposed to go to Admin and post news articles should be a Programmer too.

Comment: I never judged you for anything. It's your project. You may do as you wish. Only thing I said was, it's a complicated solution & it may be simpler to implement your own Login  system, because the admin page is not meant to be over engineered, as explained in their own [**DOCs**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/): ..., but beware of trying to use those hooks exclusively. If you need to provide a more process-centric interface that abstracts away the implementation details of database tables and fields, then it’s probably time to write your own views.

Comment: what I'm looking for has absolutely nothing to do with database.